# Changing UI state depending on a checkbox value

Tags: mfc

I have the following situation.

There is a dialog with a check-box and a text-box. Check-box's click is bound to a function that toggles if the text-box is enabled or grayed out. It works fine but I also need to preset some values to the dialog before creating and displaying it. If the variable that is connected to the check-box is set to ture I want to disable the text-box.

I tried to accomplish this in different ways, but it all boils down to the fact that I can not change the GUI of the dialog before calling `DoModal` (I get assertion falure when I try).

This is probably a common problem, but I could bot find a solution online. Am I completely off track?

```
MyDialog d(this);
d.bFlag = TRUE; // Because it is true, I want the text-box to be disabled
// I could call a function of d here that would set the state of the text-box correctly,
// but an assertion falure would happen.
if (d.DoModal() == IDOK){
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override OnInitDialog function in your dialog class MyDialog and have the code to check the check box value and enable/disable the text box.